# ScheduledExecutorService: How can I wait for cancelled tasks to finish?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I have scheduled some tasks in a `ScheduledExecutorService`. On shutdown, I'd like to cancel them, and release a database lock once they are all done.

How can I wait for the cancelled tasks to finish processing?

**Attempted solutions**

- according to my tests, `future.cancel()` does not block until the task has stopped executing
- invoking `future.get()` after `future.cancel()` results in an immediate CancelledExecutionException
- I'd rather not wait for shutdown of the entire executor, as it is shared among components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I wait for the cancelled tasks to finish processing?

The problem with this is that cancellation is done on a best effort basis. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) states

> **Attempts** to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if
> the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could
> not be cancelled for some other reason.

Typically, cancellation is implemented with interruption and interruption is a convention. Nothing guarantees that it will be implemented correctly. So even if you do send a `cancel`, nothing guarantees that the underlying task (if already running) will fulfill the cancellation.

There's no reliable way to implement your use case.

Comment: I understand that the request to cancel will not necessarily be honored, but even if it is not, the task will finish sometime. How can I wait for that time?

Comment: @meriton With a typical `ScheduledExecutorService`, afaik, you can't. Try looking into [`CompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html). Alternatively, you might be able to wrap your submitted `Runnable` instances in a `Runnable` implementation that notifies you in some way. `Future` won't do here.

Comment: Oh my, that's what I was afraid of. The CompletionService does not allow me to distinguish whether the completed tasks is one of mine, but if I have a non-shared CompletionService, I might as well use a dedicated ScheduledExecutorService that I shutdown. So it's either that or change the tasks themselves. I think I'll go with the latter, and have them implement cancellation explicity by checking a volatile field for cancellation requests.

Comment: @meriton You might also want to consider looking into subtyping `ScheduledExecutorService` and implementing a custom `afterExecute` method to notify you of completion (on cancellation). I don't think this is trivial.

Comment: I agree :-) ... if I had to do that, I'd ditch the executor and go with plain old `Thread`s, which feature that handy `join` method. Anyway, thanks for confirming that this really is surprisingly hard.